# Python: Converting a list element from readline() to integer?

Tags: python, list, file, file-io, integer

So I am trying to read a line from a text file that contains a hex number in it, and then convert it to a decimal number, then divide it by 3.

However I receive an error says:"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16:"

Here is what I did:

```
f = open('simp.txt','r')
line = f.readline()

while line:
    line = f.readline()
    temp = (int(str(line[3:11]),16))//3
    print(temp)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Edit: Here is what in my simp.txt:

```
   00000000
   000032C8
```

So the program should prints:"4333", because 13000//3=4333.

Comment: My guess would be for some lines, the data is not an int; what's in simp.txt?

Comment: What is wrong is that you are probably trying to convert a character to integer. Note that readline does not strip the '\r' or '\n' character from the string

Comment: Please give us some example input, and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps line is hitting values that don't convert to hex; for instance, int('1X',16) will give a ValueError. If this is not the issue, please print line and share the value or provide simp.txt

Comment: added the simp.txt to Edit section

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use readline, it does not strip the `\n` or `\r` character from the string, so you end up trying to convert that to an integer

Use `f.readline().strip()`

A better way to do this is:

```
with open('simp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = int(line.strip(), 16) // 3
        print(temp)
```

Comment: Another nice thing about `strip()` is that removes all leading and trailing white space from a string. It _looks_ like the lines in "simp.txt" have leading spaces, but I guess that could just be due to how the OP formatted the text when posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `line.strip()` to remove `\n` or `\r` at the end of a line.

You can try like this:

```
with open("simp.txt", "r") as fp:
    data = fp.readline()
    value = int(data.strip(), 16) / 3
    print value
```